# Widows 10 PHP 7.3.3: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\json_encode()

Tags: php, json

Browse in StackOverflow, always recommend installing package `JSON`, almost of all platform is `Linux` base. but I can't find instruction to install it in Windows.

`Php: 7.3.3;` `OS: Windows 10;` `Service: Apache 2.4`

When check with php -i, it say

`json support => enabled`

`json version => 1.7.0`

when I check in php.ini there is no `extension=json` found.

any suggestions to solve it?

Comment: There is accident when I type json_encode vsCode add line

use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;

Answer (score 1):

Use `\json_encode()` instead.

'\' at begining means "use pure PHP function" even if something overwrites it. In your case you probably also use GuzzleHttp which overwrites `json_encode()` function.